# Tweaking "Most visited sites" button in Firefox

Tags: firefox, website

It is sometimes practical to use "Most Visited" sites which stands on the left hand side of Firefox window. When I click on it, I can see maximum 10 URLs. At that point, I have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to increase the number of maximum most visited sites (say, 30)?
2. Let's say *example.com* is one of the most visited domains. In the most visited list, there are other pages from this domain, like *example.com/intro*, *example.com/info*, *example.com/help* etc. So those sub-addresses are also in the list, but I just want to see max 1 (or maybe 2) pages from the same domain in the list. Is it possible to arrange the list this way?

Comment: I don't believe so and I am also not seeing any addons that accomplish this either.

Comment: @MrStatic: No, but there are tons of add-ons that replace this functionality with their own, and they usually tend to be better (in my opinion, of course).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the documentation for "[**Places query URIs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Places_query_URIs)".

The "Most Visited" button is a bookmark to:

```
place:queryType=0&sort=8&maxResults=10
```

If you created a new bookmark to the same URI but change the "maxResults" parameter, you can increase the number of results returned.

Sort order can also be changed. 8 means "Sort by visit count, descending".

For your 2nd request, I'm not sure it can be implemented. Play with the "type" parameter, maybe 0, 1 or 2.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this results in the error message "Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (place) isn't associated with any program" when creating the bookmark in the toolbar area (where it is most sensibly located).

Solution (found after half an hour of online research): Initially creating the bookmark elsewhere and then dragging it to the Toolbar ... or if it is already there, dragging the bookmark to a bookmark folder and then back to the toolbar. That's it.